# filebeat needs to be restarted to send logs each and everytime . It does not send logs dynamically (on its own)

Tags: architecture, logstash, filebeat

My `Filebeat` is tailing the files properly(as i wanted and that's why i switched from `Logstash` forwarder to `Filebeat`).

But whenever any updates are introduced in the logfile those are not sent by my `Filebeat` to the `Logstash` dynamically and on its own .

It requires me to restart the `Filebeat` service by again typing "sudo service `Filebeat` restart" in the terminal .

So I have the following questions -

- 1. Any reason why this is happening ??
- 2. What kind of service does `Filebeat` use- TCP or UDP ??
- 3. How can I monitor how many events are sent by `Filebeat` to `Logstash` quite like logstash forwarder??

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to enable **info** logging level on your filebeat configuration. Is the last section of your **/etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml** file.

Then try to add content to your monitored file by:

```
echo "some noise!!" >> /path/to/monitoredfile.txt
```

What do the log file says? If don't see anything, try to use the **debug** level. There you should find your answer.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Yes this helped . Actually this was what I had a strong intuition earlier but I could not convince myself with any sound reason. Now I think I have a clear reason for this . What happens is that when I am manually updating files the corresponding event for change does not gets fired and when updates are made automatically (through bash script or something). Thats why my Filebeat was not able to  detect changes in the log file and I had to restart it manually . Things sorted ...

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you, XD.

Would you mind to check my answer as correct?